# DB9 Serial communication

Tags: serial-port

I am getting some strange character displays on hyper terminal, after establishing communication with my GSM modem using the appropriate baud rate. When I type "AT", it appears to get repeated  or display strange characters (as though the baud rate were not correct) on the hyper terminal screen as "AATT". And all other AT commands get repeated as well, but what surprises me is that they all respond to the command. "AATT"(having typed "AT") give me "OK".

What could possibly be the problem? I am connecting the Modem to the DB9 using a MAX232. Below is the response

---

øatt
OK
aaütø
OK
aatt++ücnnmmiiþ?ø
+CNMI: 1,0,0,0,0

OK
aattþ+ccssccss??ø
+CSCS: "UCS2"

OK

RING

RING

RING

NO CARRIER
øat++ücnnmmii==11<,22<,00,,00,,00ø
OK
aattþ+ccssccss==""GGêSMM""ø
OK
Øaüt++ccmmögæf==11ø
OK
 aatt
OK

aaüt++ccþnmii??
+CNMI: 1,2,0,0,0

OK

---

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the echo option enabled in your terminal emulator program, so what happens you send the character, your terminal emulator prints it on the screen and at the same time the modem at the other end echos the character back to you so you see it twice.

However, since the mode only gets the character once, it is fine for it.

It's basically a cosmetic problem really. You can fix it if you want by turning off the ehco characters option in your terminal emulator program

Comment: Thanks. I turned off the echo and the repetition was gone, but displayed strange characters. So how do one explain the presence of the strange characters displayed.

Comment: I am using a baud rate of 9600. So i changed the baud rate to 115200 and it worked well. No repetition. But my intended application is for the 9600 baudrate, and such repetition will sure be a problem. Could it be a Max232 issue?

Comment: You need to tell your modem to switch to 9600 baud then.

Comment: The classical command to set fixed baud rate is `AT+IPR` (check V.250).